# Why doesn't my page render properly in Internet Explorer?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, layout

I have a simple but strange problem.

I can't resolve it after giving so many tries I have a table here is the screenshot for **Mozilla:**
[image: In Mozilla]

It also looks good in **Chrome**:
[image: In chrome]

But the problem occurs in **IE**.

[image: In Internet Explorer]

[here the fiddle with all the code](http://jsfiddle.net/arisingpopli/gQXPn/)

How to do it right in IE?

The table gaping

map hides after using div instead of iframe

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can put the `iframe` in a table to align with the above tables(Contact Details)
for example given in the http://jsfiddle.net/BEBdv/
I tested in **IE8:**
[image]
I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Just set `height:auto` to your top most `<div>` tag that wraps everything.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/gQXPn/2/

Answer (score -3):

The problem is because of the use of iframe tag which is not supported by IE
(Source: http://caniuse.com/#search=iframe)
You can easily use a div tag instead of iframe and all should be fine.

Comment: Not working div instead of iframe hide the map and not effect on table look and feel